# Remaining Instagram API Life Expectancy

Tags: tags, media, instagram-api

After the recent changes in the Instagram API, what is the life expectancy of the remaining endpoints? Users, Media, Comments, Tags

Specifically I'm considering an integration with the "Tags" endpoint.  Anyone have insights there?

Answer (score 0):

Most of these Instagram APIs will be deprecated by Dec 11, 2018.
Here is communication from Facebook.

> These capabilities will be disabled immediately  (previously set for
>   July 31, 2018 or December 11, 2018 deprecation). The following will be
>   deprecated according to the timeline we shared previously:
>
> ```
> Public Content - all remaining capabilities to read public media on a user's behalf on December 11, 2018
> Basic - to read a user’s own profile info and media in early 2020
> For your reference, information on the new Instagram Graph API.
> ```

https://www.instagram.com/developer/

Facebook introduced Instagram graph APIs

https://developers.facebook.com/products/instagram/

Comment: Thanks @manish. I'm mostly interested to know about the Tags endpoint.  I don't see any specific details when they plan to deprecate it.  Dec 2018, or in the complete deprecation in 2020?  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/